# Use clarirty design date picker without angular

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vmware-clarity

I am building Vue.Js application which uses Clarity Design. The library doesn't support officially Vue, so I'm using just the css classes and make custom components with them. But I faced a problem with the date picker, because it's supported only for Angular and can't see a solution to use it in Vue. Is there any way to use it in my application.

Comment: Could you use Bootstrap Vue's date picker - https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-datepicker ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently Clarity only works with Angular. We have an initiative to make Clarity framework independent underway, but today the only option is to use Clarity with Angular to get the datepicker and other features.

See: https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/clarity-core-72f6d3a029bc